# Microsoftless C# development system for Windows

Tags: c#, windows

If you were given a new computers with Windows ( XP or Vista ) and had to install a development system for C# which used as little as it could of stuff created at Microsoft, how would you do it?

PS:
I want to make clear ( since it seems I initially didn't ), I do not mean an IDE.
I mean a system. Suppose I install XP or Vista without installing .Net.

What "components" ie compilers, runtimes and  libraries do I have to install to make develop in C# and how can i do it using as few Microsoft products as I can.

Comment: Why are you using Microsoft Windows XP or Vista, in that case? Use a "Microsoft-less" OS.

Comment: I do, much of the time, but there are times when I am using a MS OS and would like to have a development system which does not tie me to a MS OS.

Comment: After your "PS", my answer is still 'the answer'; simply because There are only two ways to really use C# - and one of those is using Mono for their open-source port of the .NET Framework and using them to compile.

Answer (score 22):

The question is, Why aren't you using Microsoft products for a product created by Microsoft?

If the answer is **cost** then have a looksee at the free version of the C# IDE and Compiler, [Visual Studio Express](http://www.microsoft.com/Express/).

If there are other reasons, then you can always use your own text editor, [download Mono](http://www.mono-project.com/Main_Page) and get the [Mono C# compiler](http://www.mono-project.com/CSharp_Compiler) and compile everything yourself. If you're looking for an alternative IDE, [SharpDevelop is available](http://sharpdevelop.com/).

Comment: Because Microsoft products have a way of forcing people to stay with Microsoft products, even when they don't want to.

Comment: @BubbaT: er... then why use C#?  C# is a Microsoft developed language... and there is a non-Microsoft language that is quite similar to it (Java).

Comment: I know this is an old question, but just want to make the point that C# != Microsoft. Mono and DotGNU are great implementations of both C# and the CLI specification. Worth nothing too that, unlike Java, C# is an ISO standard as well as an ECMA Language (like JavaScript). There are some really great reasons to use it even if you have no interest in writing software for (or on) Microsoft platforms.

Answer (score 6):

In terms of development IDE one of your best bets would be [SharpDevelop](http://www.icsharpcode.net/OpenSource/SD/)

If you want to go a step further and not even use the Microsoft compiler you can use [Mono](http://www.mono-project.com/Mono:Windows) (C# only).

Answer (score 5):

The .NET Framework itself comes with a compiler and build system (csc/msbuild, the equivalent of gcc/make) *built in*. It's in C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\v3.5. All you really need to build .NET code is a copy of Notepad (or preferably, Vim)

Answer (score 2):

- [CSharpBuilder](http://www.codegear.com/downloads/free/csharpbuilder)
- [Sharp Develop](http://www.icsharpcode.net/OpenSource/SD/)

  [Mono](http://www.mono-project.com/Main_Page)

Comment: C#Builder is no longer available.

Answer (score 1):

I have heard about [Sharp develop](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SharpDevelop)

Answer (score 1):

You could use Eclipse, Mono and a C# plugin. For the more complex stuff you could use the command line for compiling.

Answer (score 0):

I had used ASP.Net Web Matrix to develop some web site in c#1.0 years ago. Its free, lite & easy to use.

Comment: But it's completely obsolete and only supports ASP.NET 1.0. And anyway, it is a Microsoft product ;)

Comment: Ok .. wasnt aware of that ... had used it in 2005 ... so its pretty old i guess considering the frequency with which microsoft launches new versions and tools .. :D